# Marionette `close()` or `empty()`

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

In my app I am adding views to `content` region and `header,footer`. before I add a view, I am trying to find if there is a controller exist. if so i am trying to close those regions before I add another like this:

```
if(socialApp.Controller) {
 socialApp.Controller.layout.header.close();
 socialApp.Controller.layout.content.close();
 socialApp.Controller.layout.footer.close();
}
```

But I am getting error.

Instead of close i used the `empty()` method is works fine.

```
if(socialApp.Controller) {
     socialApp.Controller.layout.header.empty();
     socialApp.Controller.layout.content.empty();
     socialApp.Controller.layout.footer.empty();
    }
```

what I do is correct? any one confirm me please?
Note : Do I need to `close` the controller / views as well..!?
I am using `Backbone.Marionette` `v2.1.0`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Marionette v2.1.0 Region docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.1.0/marionette.region.html#preventdestroy)

> If you replace the current view with a new view by calling show, by default it will automatically destroy the previous view.

From [LayoutView](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.1.0/marionette.layoutview.html#re-rendering-a-layoutview)

> After the first render, all subsequent renders will force every region to be emptied by calling the empty method on them. This will force every view in the region, and sub-views if any, to be destroyed as well.

Thus I think you **don't need** to `empty()` them manually

Comment: Ok, so how about the `memory leak` issues handles? is `marionette` take care about this as well..?

Comment: Generally I would say yes. [Here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/583) is nice post about the topic.